# Error while load-time compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I created an Aspectj project and added .aj files and java files. While compiling(Load-time) it shows the error

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class javaagent:path/aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar"
```

I compiled it in eclipse by creating Load time configuration file.
Can any one tell me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: Probably you should provide a real file system path instead of the place holder *path*. Also be sure to use `-javaagent:...` (note the dash character) instead of something like `javaagent:...`.